# How to reference a String array subscript with an Int

Tags: java, arrays

My goal is to get a list of five names from the user and store them in an array. I then need to show the user a list of the names (with integers before each name) and allow the user to select which friend is his/her best friend.
I have gotten it completed to the part where I need the user's input to indicate their best friend. The user's input needs to be an integer, whereas my array of names is a String array. I am having difficulty getting a user provided Int to reference a specific subscript within the String array of names.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question5
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter five names");

        String[] names = new String[6];
        for (int subscript = 1; subscript <= 5; subscript++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter friend " + subscript);
            names[subscript] = keyboard.next();
        }
        System.out.println("Here are all of those names");
        for (int subscript = 1; subscript <= 5; subscript++)
        {
            System.out.println("Friend " + subscript + " is " + names[subscript]);
        }
        System.out.println("Which friend is your best friend? (Enter an integer)");
        names[1] = "1"; names[2] = "2"; names[3] = "3"; names[4] = "4"; names[5] = "5"; //I am not sure if this line is helpful or needs to be deleted.

    }
}
```

Comment: That last line is not helpful.  It wipes out the five names that were input by the user.  I suspect you want `int choice = keyboard.nextInt();`.  Then you can use `choice` as an array subscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the user input to an integer, something like below, and show the best friend selected :

```
int bestFriend = Integer.parseInt( keyboard.next() );
//names[1] = "1"; names[2] = "2"; names[3] = "3"; names[4] = "4"; names[5] = "5"; //I am not sure if this line is helpful or needs to be deleted.
System.out.println("You have selected " + names[bestFriend]);
```

Answer (score 1):

use `keyboard.nextInt()` to get the choice from the user and then retrieve the name from the array:

```
System.out.println("Which friend is your best friend? (Enter an integer)");
System.out.println("You chose: " + names[keyboard.nextInt()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate on the given answers:

- arrays start at index 0 in Java, you are "wasting" the first element when you create an array of length 6 just to start iterating at index 1
- [Scanner.nextInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) or [Scanner.next()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) operate on tokens (by default tokens are separated by whitespace characters). While this may not be relevant to this question imagine a list of 15 elements where the user has to select an index on the console. If the user inputs "11" all is ok, but if he accidentally adds a space ("1 1"), 1 is selected, although the input should be invalid (no number contains spaces). This is why i prefer to use [Scanner.nextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) and parse the result instead of using the previous methods.

Coming to an end, this is a sample implementation of the points above:

```
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FriendSelector {
    private static class InvalidSelectionException extends RuntimeException {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -8022487103346887887L;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FriendSelector friendSelector = new FriendSelector();

        String[] friends = friendSelector.promptUserForFriendList(5);
        System.out.println(); // Add a newline for separation.

        // Present the list of friends to the user.
        System.out.println("These are your entered friends:");
        printList(friends);
        System.out.println(); // Add a newline for separation.

        // Let the user select his/her best friend.
        int bestFriendIndex;
        do {
            bestFriendIndex = friendSelector.promptUserForBestFriend(friends);
        } while (bestFriendIndex == -1);

        System.out.printf("You selected %s as your best friend.\n", friends[bestFriendIndex]);
    }

    /**
     * Print a list to the console. Format: "[index + 1] element".
     *
     * @param list the list, not null
     */
    private static void printList(String[] list) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(list);

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("[%d] %s\n", (i + 1), list[i]);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Note that this scanner MUST NOT be closed, this would possibly interfere with
     * other program parts which operate on System.in.
     */
    private final Scanner scanner;

    public FriendSelector() {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    /**
     * Prompt the user to populate a list of friends.
     *
     * @param length how many friends should be named
     * @return a list of friend names
     */
    public String[] promptUserForFriendList(int length) {
        if (length <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("length must be positive");
        }

        System.out.printf("Enter the names of %s friends, please.\n", length);

        String[] names = new String[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Name %d: ", i + 1);
            names[i] = scanner.nextLine();
        }

        return names;
    }

    /**
     * Prompt the user to select the best friend of the provided friends.
     *
     * @param friends an array of friend names, must be non-null
     * @return the index of the best friend, or -1 if none valid entry was selected.
     */
    public int promptUserForBestFriend(String[] friends) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(friends);

        try {
            System.out.printf("Which friend is your best friend [1,%d]: ", friends.length);

            // Get the selected array index.
            String selectionString = scanner.nextLine();
            int selection = Integer.parseInt(selectionString);
            int selectedIndex = selection - 1;

            if (selectedIndex < 0 || selectedIndex >= friends.length) {
                throw new InvalidSelectionException();
            }

            return selectedIndex;
        } catch (NumberFormatException | InvalidSelectionException e) {
            System.out.printf("Invalid input: You didn't enter an integer in the range [1,%d]\n", friends.length);
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```